# Is there a better way to access the Document from its subviews?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument, nsundomanager, document-based

I have some classes located on my Document such as NSNotificationCenter and NSUndoManager that I need access to from my subviews.

Right now I can access them by doing something like this:

```
NSUndoManager *undoManager = [[[[[self view] window] windowController] document] undoManager];
```

Is there a better approach I don't know about?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why does a view need to worry about the undo manager? Seems like some refactoring might be in order there.

Normally, the view might trigger some action in the first responder. That action then gets passed up the responder chain until it finds an object, such as the window controller or document, that responds to that action. An 'undo' event generally affects the data model, so the document would handle something like that. When the user undoes a previous operation, the model is reverted back to a prior state, and the view hierarchy reflects the change.

Is it possible in your case to move the responsibility for dealing with the undo manager up to the document?

The same could apply to the notification center. If the document has a notification center, why is the view trying to use it? Can you leverage the responder chain as described above to get a message to the document? There's also a default notification center that you can get with `+defaultNotificationCenter` if that's more appropriate.

Comment: Agreed: The document class and other model classes should, in the vast majority of the cases, be the ones responsible for telling the undo manager about undo/redo operations.

Comment: I'd like for my Document's subviews to receive notifications only  relevant to them.  If a subview uses the defaultNotificationCenter, it would receive notifications from other Documents. What I was thinking is that there would be something the equivalent of an  Application Delegate but for Documents. You are right that a refactor may be in order though.

Comment: Views usually don't care too much about other views, except where locating and drawing subviews and that sort of thing is concerned. Send a message up the responder chain and forget about it. If there's some notifying that needs to be done, let the document or window controller post the notification. When views depend on the content or behavior of other views, moving your views around suddenly becomes very difficult.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can do.